# Why Do I Keep Getting This CORS Error With Firebase

Tags: firebase, cors

I keep getting this same CORS error when trying to perform basic requests with the Firebase real-time database.

Ive followed 2 separate tutorials on how to request/post data to/from the Firebase real-time database and every time I reload the page it comes up saying:

```
Access to script at 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ProjectName*******/database/data/' (redirected from 'https://***ProjectName*****-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/') from origin 'http://localhost:5005' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have googled this and have tried many solutions, some from this site and nothing has helped.

Ive installed GSUTIL and tried to modify the CORS rules through that...
Eg. Running `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket` Through GSUTIL
It just returns 'No file in directory'

I then tried putting a cors.json file in my firestore and it still doesn't help

Im just at a loss and have no idea what to do now

I am just getting started with coding and know nothing about CORS

So please take note of that...
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *I [...] know nothing about CORS.* Take the time to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. You should have a better idea of what to do then.

Answer (score 1):

When importing `getDatabase` to use the Firebase RTDB, you don't want to use either of these:

```js
import { getDatabase, ... } from "https://[PROJECT_ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
```

```js
const { getDatabase, ... } = await import("https://[PROJECT_ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
```

This is because neither of these are importing the Firebase Web SDK.

To import the Firebase Web SDK for the RTDB in a build environment, you would use either of these:

```js
import { getDatabase, ... } from "firebase/database"
```

```js
const { getDatabase, ... } = await import("firebase/database");
```

To import the Firebase Web SDK for the RTDB in a browser, you would use either of these:

```js
import { getDatabase, ... } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-database.js"
```

```js
const { getDatabase, ... } = await import("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-database.js");
```

The URL of your database normally goes into the Firebase configuration object you pass to `initializeApp` like so:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com", // <-- here
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Then when you need to use it, you just call either of these as needed:

```js
// uses default app & default database
const database = getDatabase();
```

```js
// uses given app & default database
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

When you are using more than one RTDB instance (shared from another project, different region, etc), you pass in the URL of that instance as the second argument like so:

```js
// uses default app & given database
const secondDatabase = getDatabase(getApp(), "https://secondDatabaseName.firebaseio.com");
```

```js
// uses given app & given database
const secondDatabase = getDatabase(app, "https://secondDatabaseName.firebaseio.com");
```

Comment: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[PROJECT_ID] << this link was refering to the import of 'getDatabase' - I solved this problem but im not really sure what i did. 

Thank you

Comment: @Wan33 oh, I see now. You tried to use something like `import { getDatabase } from "https://[PROJECT_ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"` which redirects to the Firebase Console when accessed directly. Check out the updated answer.